# wpcf7_add_form_tag not working on Hostinger

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following code which works great on the staging environment but doesn't work on the live website (different hostings). The [current_url] tag in the CF7 form is not rendering at all.
I tried changing the PHP version but it doesn't help and there are no PHP errors/warnings.

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_current_url' );

function wpcf7_add_form_tag_current_url() {
    // Add shortcode for the form [current_url]
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'current_url',
        'wpcf7_current_url_form_tag_handler',
        array(
            'name-attr' => true
        )
    );
}

// Parse the shortcode in the frontend
function wpcf7_current_url_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    global $wp;
    $url = get_home_url( $wp->request, $scheme = 'relative' );
    $urlenc = str_replace('/','',$url);
    return '<input type="hidden" name="origin" value="'. urlencode($urlenc) .'" />';
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

I tried changing php versions, clearing the cache, updating all plugins but the doesn't help